# Sorting an array with pointers in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

what's supposed to happen in the code is that the user is to enter in a number for the array and then a function is used to sort the array with pointers in correct order. The problem is, the output isn't coming out as it should and I don't know what I am doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MINIMUM_QUANTITY  2
#define MAXIMUM_QUANTITY  10
#define QUIT              0

int quantityValue();
float obtainInfo(int data);
float dataSort(float array1[], float newArray[]);

int main()
{
   int   quantity;
   float *fdata,

   while(quantityValue(quantity)) != QUIT)
   {
      if (fdata = (float*)malloc(sizeof(*fdata) * quantity) == NULL)
      {  
         exit(0);
      }

      obtainInfo(fdata, quantity);
      dataSort(fdata, quantity);

      free(fdata);
   }
   return 0;
}

int quantityValue()
{
   int choice;

   do
   {
      printf("\nHow many numbers are there?");
      scanf("%d", &choice);
   }
   while(choice > MINIMUM_QUANTITY || choice < MAXIMUM_QUANTITY);
   return choice;
}

float obtainInfo(int data)
{
   float array[data],
         value;

   for(counter = 0; counter <= array[data]; counter++)
   {
      printf("\nvalue %d", counter + 1);
      scanf("%f", value);     
      array[data] = value;
      array++;

   return array[data];
}

float dataSort(float array1[], float newArray[])
{
   int *startOfData
       *data
       *startOfSort
       *sort
       *biggestNumber
       temp;

   if(p_sort = (float*)malloc(sizeof(*p_sort) == NULL)
   {
      exit(0);
   }

   for(startOfData = array1[]; startOfData < biggestNumber; startOfData++
   {
      for(startOfSort = newArray; startOfSort < startOfData; startOfSort++)
      {
         temp = *data; 
         *data = *sort;
         *sort = temp;

    free(p_sort)
    return;
}
```

Comment: Oh wait, I just noticed that I'm missing some code in my one function. My apologies.

Comment: The compiler gives numerous warnings and errors.

Comment: The way you are using your functions don't even match how you are using them in `main()`.  For instance, how to you expect `quanityValue()` to save its result in the local `quantity`?  You have nothing like `quantity = quanityValue();` The signature of `dataSort()` is mismatched too.   Does this even compile?

Comment: @infixed: No, it doesn't compile. The first flagged error is a mismatched parenthesis on line 18. Paul, we need to see your real code.

Comment: Consider developing it incrementally.  save your current work, but start a new file, with just `main()` and `quanityValue()` in it, then use the debugger to get that working.   One you have that, work on loading your array, and debug that,  after that works, work on sorting.  You don't have to do it all at once.

Comment: `obtainInfo()` is declared to take one argument, but you call it with two arguments, how is that supposed to work? And `counter <= array[data]` should be `counter < data`. `return array[data];` accesses outside the array boundary. But I suspect you're trying to return the array itself, not just a single element of the array. You can't return a local array from a function.

Comment: This code has a lot of syntax errors and won't even compile. Please copy and paste the actual code you are having trouble with

Answer (score 0):

To sort an array there are multiple algorithms that can help you, one of the most used is Quick Sort. Here there is the complete code for sorting an array:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void Swap(int array[], int i, int j)
{
  int temp;
  temp = array[i];
  array[i] = array[j];
  array[j] = temp;
}


void QuickSort(int array[], int beg, int end)
{
  int pivot, k, b, e;

    while(beg < end)
    {
      b = beg; k = (beg+end)/2; e = end;
      pivot = array[k];

      while(1)
      {
        while((b <= e) && (array[b] <= pivot)) b++;
        while((b <= e) && (array[e] > pivot)) e--;

        if(b > e) break;


      Swap(array, b, e);

        if(k == e) k = b;

        b++; e--;

      }
      array[k]=array[e];
      array[e]=pivot;
      e--;

      if((e-beg)<(end-b))
      {
        QuickSort(array, beg, e);
        beg = b;
      }
      else
      {
        QuickSort(array, b, end);
        end = e;
      }

    }

  return ;
}

void display(int * array, int n)
{
 for(int i = 0; i < n ; i++)
 {
   printf("%d\n", array[i]);
 }
}


int main()
{
  int array[] = {1,2,77,5,42,33,0,4,12,21,55}; //array to sort, instead you can use a function that fills an array, and then pass it to QuickSort function

  QuickSort(array,0,sizeof(array)/sizeof(int));

  display(array, sizeof(array)/sizeof(int));


  return 0;
}
```